# Show that the sentence or the negation of a sentence is provable from the theory of discrete total orders

Tags: logic, model-theory

"Consider the structure $\mathcal{N} = (\mathbb{N}, \leq)$: the natural numbers with the usual ordering (without $0$). Let $\Sigma$ be the set of sentences stating that $\leq$ is a discrete total (i.e., linear) order with an initial point but without a final point. Prove that for every sentence $\varphi$ we have: $\Sigma \vdash \varphi$ or $\Sigma \vdash \neg \varphi$."

Here's what I have so far: I think the set of sentences in $\Sigma$ are:

- Transitive, reflexive, antisymmetric axioms
- Linearity (i.e., $\forall x \forall y: x \leq y \vee y \leq x$)
- There is a smallest element (i.e., $\exists x \forall y: x \leq y$)

My guess is to use Gödel's Completeness Theorem (that is, $\Sigma \vdash \varphi \iff \Sigma \models \varphi$), so we instead have to prove that $\Sigma \models \varphi$ or $\Sigma \models \neg \varphi$. But I'm not sure where to proceed from there.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Is "discrete total order" not defined in the book the problem is from? I wonder why  we are asked to "consider" the structure $\mathcal N,$ which is not mentioned again in the question? I **don't know** but I'm going to **guess** that $\Sigma$ is supposed to be the theory of the structure $\mathcal N.$ Besides the axioms you listed, you need one saying that there is **no greatest element** ("without a final point"). And I **guess** "discrete" means that every element which is not the smallest has an **immediate** predecessor, and every element has an **immediate** successor.

Comment: How would prove it would depend on what you already know, what tools you have available. Do you know what it means for two structures to be *elementarily equivalent*? Do you have some technique for proving that two structures are elementarily equivalent? If so, one way to prove that $\Sigma$ is complete would be to show that all models of $\Sigma$ are elementarily equivalent, by showing that every model of $\Sigma$ is elementarily equivalent to $\mathcal N.$

Comment: The question was directly quoted from a past exam. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a definition for "discrete total order" anywhere, but to my knowledge your guess is correct

Comment: I do know what elementary equivalence is. Your comment gave me an idea - can we use Ehrenfeucht-Fraisse games to prove elementary equivalence?

Comment: The other tools I have available which may be helpful are ultraproducts, diagrams, and quantifier elimination

Comment: Personally, I'd try using Ehrenfeucht–Fraisse games. Elimination of quantifiers may also be a good method.